# How to hit a Retrofit URL containing colon (:)?

Tags: java, android, url, httpclient, retrofit2

This is the URL that I want to hit using Retrofit2. 
http://makecodeeasy.com:49166/api/Customers

```
@POST(":49166/api/Customers")
Observable<LoginResponse>
login( @Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

**Here is my RetroClient**:

```
public static Retrofit callInstance() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();


    String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com";
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}
```

> I am getting the 404 Not Found error.

Comment: add the port number in ROOT_URL

String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com:49166";

and change

@POST("/api/Customers")

Comment: you can specify (:) in your base url

Comment: Yes @ Adbul Ahad is right change `String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com";` to `String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com:";` or `String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com:49166";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are doing mistake you need to add your port number inside of base url you can add relative url at api calling time but In base url you need to pass full base path which includes port number also.

Change your base as following

```
String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com:49166";
```

And Relative Path Like

```
@POST("/api/Customers")
```

Answer (score 1):

The number 49166 is the port number on the URL.

Your ROOT_URL should be:

```
String ROOT_URL = "http://makecodeeasy.com:49166";
```

And use Retrofit as:

```
@POST("api/Customers")
Observable<LoginResponse>
login( @Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```